# TypeError: 'Figure' object is not iterable (itertools)

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-itertools

```
import itertools

axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(15,15))

axs_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(axs))
for ax in axs_list:

    ax.plot(gen_stock_price_array2())
```

When I use itertools.chain.from_iterable, I have a type error. I have searched Google, but I can't find an answer. I am wondering if others may have the same question, for me, it is kind of strange.

Type Error pic:
[image]

Comment: `plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(15,15))` returns a 2-element tuple: the first element is the `Figure` and the second is the set of `Axes`. You probably want `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(axs[1]))`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I used your method and have fixed it.

Comment: It would help if you included the actual text of the type error instead of a PNG link. People trying to help can solve your problem much faster, and it helps others quickly see if they might be having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(15,15))` returns a 2-element tuple: the first element is the Figure and the second is the set of Axes.

You probably want the following:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(15,15))

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.plot(gen_stock_price_array2())
```

I hope this serves some purpose.